# float:left does not work in CSS stylesheet

Tags: css, html

I put two div in one div, and float three of them, but the inside two does not float at all, even through I typed the CSS code. Is there something I missing? Thank you very much.
Do I mistakenly typed something, or is there a format mistake.

**CSS**

```
#product-viewing {
    float:left;
}

#sign_up { 
    float:left;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="product-viewing">
    <div id="hyperlink">
        <a href="index.html">Home</a> &mdash; <a href="login_sign.html" class="active">Login | Sign Up</a>
    </div>
    <div id="login">
        <h1 class="accounts-title">Customer Login</h1>
        <form method='post' action=''></form> 
    </div>  
    <div id="sign_up">  
        <h1 class="accounts-title">Create Account</h1>
        <form method='post' action='' id='create_customer'></form>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Comment: I don't see product-viewing in your HTML...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this

you right `#product-viewing` but in `your html` `not shown this selector`

so please write `#login` replace of `#product-viewing`

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3GN9w/)**

**css**

```
#login {
    float: left;
    background-color:red;
}
#sign_up {
    float: left;
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

---

**[demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/3GN9w/2/)**

**css**

```
#product-viewing {
    float: left;
    background-color:red;
}
#sign_up, #login {
    float: left;
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you must have a div with id="product-viewing" to apply the CSS

Answer (score 0):

Add this Css

```
#sign_up, #login { float:left;}
```

Check the jsfiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/7gbNK/56/

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand ... because this #product-viewing {float:left;} pointless!

must be added #login {float:left;}.....if do you want to put with the width ....do like that

#sign_up,#login { float: left;width:50%;}